# How does the flag at?

Tags: sass, susy, susy-sass

There is a grid span(12)

[image]

There are two blocks of text

```
.main-container
    .content text text text text text text text text text 
    .sidebar text text text text text text text text text
```

Want to do so

[image]

Write the code

```
span(6 at 1) //
span(3 as 9) //
```

But don't get desired. Here's the whole code.

```
$debug: (image: show, color: rgba(#66f, .25), output: background, toggle: top right)

$susy: (columns: 12, gutters: 1/4, math: fluid, gutter-position: inside, debug: $debug)

.main-container
    @include container(80%)

.content
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    @include span(6 at 1)

.sidebar
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    @include span(3 at 9)
```

I thought that the flag `at` designed exactly for this purpose. But experiment has shown that I'm wrong. On this question - how to work with the flag `at`? ow to achieve the desired result using the `at`?

Answer (score 0):

The `at` flag is only used in this way for isolation output (`'output': 'isolate'`). That's because floats are relative, and Susy doesn't know their original position unless you isolate them. Isolation is useful in some cases, but it's better to use `push` and `pull` to move floated elements into relative positions when needed. Something like this:

```
.content {
  height: 100%;
  @include span(6);
  @inlcude push(1);
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  @include span(3);
  @include push(1);
}
```

If you do use isolation, it would be something like this:

```
.content {
  height: 100%;
  @include span(isolate 6 at 2); // position is 1-indexed
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  @include span(isolate 3 at 9);
}
```

I removed `width: 100%` because `span` overrides width anyway.